# SearchBar in NavigationBar IOS 11

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uisearchbar

I tried using Navigation Bar Large Title and adding Search Bar to Navigation Controller. The Search Bar is displayed under the Navigation title. It should be hidden until I swipe down. I understand that the default behavior is hidden unless I set "navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = false". Even I add "navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = true", it doesn't work.

I created a new app to test this function. It has ViewController and Navigation Controller embedded. Below is my code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
        navigationItem.searchController = searchController
        // navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = true

    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, and what is the problem?

Comment: The search bar should be hidden. It only displays the search bar when I swipe down.

Comment: The problem is Toolbar on top of TableView in Storyboard. When move the Toolbar under TableView, the large title and hidden search bar are working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered with a similar situation. I've solved like this:

1- Remove everything about searchController

2- Add UISearchBar control into your table

[image]

3- Connect this searchBar control to a IBOutlet variable and set delegate

```
searchBar.delegate = self
```

4- Use only UISearchBarDelegate (remove UISearchResultsUpdating) and implement **textDidChange** method

```
func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
    filter...
    reload table...
}
```

this table header search bar works with iOS 11 and older versions

Comment: When I add the searchBar to the tableView it is displayed bellow the cells instead of above. Any ideas on how to fix it?