# searchBar should not be visible when showing view - ios 11

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have similar problem like here:
[SearchBar in NavigationBar IOS 11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46511382/searchbar-in-navigationbar-ios-11)
In my case I don't have toolbar on top of TableView.

I added searchBar in my VC:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UISearchController * search = [[UISearchController alloc] initWithSearchResultsController:nil];
    search.searchResultsUpdater = self;
    self.navigationItem.searchController = search;
    self.navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = YES;

    self.navigationController.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = NO;
    self.navigationController.navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = UINavigationItemLargeTitleDisplayModeNever;
}
```

Now searchBar is always visible. It should be hide by default. SearchBar should showed when I pull the tableView down.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that I add picture to background:

```
UIImageView *background = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"somethingImage"]];
[background setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
[self.view addSubview:background];
[self.view sendSubviewToBack:background];
```

Then Search controller has some problem. I don't know how to repair it. I think it is an apple bug.